# Arrange Category post manually when displayed

Tags: php, query, html, cms

Is there way to display the category post manually or in a specific order. Basically the post are arranged in alphabetical order. It is a clients request

[image]

Here is the code for category post

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&cat=4');; if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post_project">
            <div class="project_thumbnail">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<img src="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '"></a>';  } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="hotel_thumb">
             <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a class="learn_more" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Learn More">Learn More</a>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

It would be such a hassle if i have to query or call each post instead

Comment: So, you want to sort your categories, right?

Comment: the post inside the categories basically the parent category "Sort by Location". Can't see an option where i can sort them to my liking or manually

Comment: I'm still no clear with you. You are trying to sort the Category, or Posts?

Comment: the post inside the parent category "Sort by location". Basically when i query the post inside the parent category "Sort by Location" it is displayed alphabetically. I need to know how i can arrange the post in my liking or manually instead of alphabetically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I can clearly get you, you want to sort the order of your posts. I found the following plugin best fit for the purpose:

- [**Post Type Order** - WordPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/)

After installing the plugin, you will get a new submenu under "Posts" (and under all other Custom Post Types). You can order the post there, and it'll sort the specific post to specific order.

It it's done, then it'll be displayed **the same order under all the categories** too. :(

Comment: Alright let me check it out :D